# When I test my quarkus resource endpoint my main service is getting called

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus

So Basically i have a ResourceTest.class and MockService.class under src/test/java.
ResourceFile is like the following

```
@QuarkusTest
public class ResourceTest {

    @Test
    public void testFetch()  {
        
        given().queryParam("fromTime", 0)
                .queryParam("toTime", 0)
                .queryParam("skip", 0)
                .queryParam("limit", 5)
                .queryParam("search", "")
                .port(80)
                .when().get("http://localhost/fetch")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body( is(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BaseResponse.create(true, "Fetched.", Utils.populatePages(list,0,5,5)))));
    }
}
```

My Mock Service file looks like this..

```
@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
public class MockService extends Service {

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<BaseResponse> fetch(String encounterId, String providerId, String patientId, long fromTime, long toTime, int skip, int limit, String search, Boolean isResolve) {
        
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BaseResponse.create
                (true, "Fetched.", Utils.populatePages(list, 0, 5, 5)));
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my testFetch() method, My main service file gets called instead of MockServicefile..
What should i do to make my mockService get called..?

Comment: Resolved it, I was running the main app on port 80. In my test endpoint i alos mentioned the port 80. So whenever i was calling my endpoint Instead of MockService by default it was pointing to main Service... Sorry for the trouble..

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer per-test mocks injection over `@Mock` bean replacement for scoped CDI beans when using `io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusMock`.

*Quarkus* provides out of the box integration with *Mockito* allowing to mock CDI scoped beans with the `io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.@InjectMock` annotation.

```java
@QuarkusTest
public class ResourceTest {

    @InjectMock
    MockService mockService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        // Here you can override the wide mock bean behavior per-each test
        Mockito.when(mockService.fetch(any(),any(),any(),any(),any(),any(),any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BaseResponse.create
            (true, "Fetched.", Utils.populatePages(list, 0, 5, 5))));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFetch()  {
        
        given().queryParam("fromTime", 0)
                .queryParam("toTime", 0)
                .queryParam("skip", 0)
                .queryParam("limit", 5)
                .queryParam("search", "")
                .port(80)
                .when().get("http://localhost/fetch")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body( is(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BaseResponse.create(true, "Fetched.", Utils.populatePages(list,0,5,5)))));
    }

    //@Mock: No @Mock annotation needed
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class MockService extends Service {

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<BaseResponse> fetch(String encounterId, String providerId, String patientId, long fromTime, long toTime, int skip, int limit, String search, Boolean isResolve) {
            // Here you can have your wide-test methods mock implementations
             return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(BaseResponse.create
                (true, "Fetched.", Utils.populatePages(list, 0, 5, 5)));
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include the `quarkus-junit5-mockito` integration artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I coudn't call the mockService in the setup() method, since mockService is a non-static variable.
Also, Should i be using InjectMock on Service(main file) or the one i created extending the main service file( MockService) ?

Comment: I fixed the lifecycle method, it should be `non-static` method with `@BeforeEach` annotation. I am sorry for confusion as I mixed two approches.
I updated the answer as well per your annotation question.